# How to send jpg to backend though to cloudinary?

Tags: javascript, node.js, file, file-upload, cloudinary

I have the following:

`fil = file:///storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.test/files/Pictures/7601d776-7ca4-44b0-99cf-d8c0bb4c14e9.jpg` , (`Image.path` for android Generated by `react-native-image-crop-picker` . when I use the below code to send this to the backend, it has an error with cloudinary while the `Image.path` for IOS  `fil = /Users/test/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/.../data/Containers/Data/Application/.../tmp/react-native-image-crop-picker/.../.jpg` does not have an error. Why is this the cases since they are both grabbed from `Image.path` for `react-native-image-crop-picker` ?

```
const res = await client.post('/upload-avatar',{fil},{headers:{
        Accept : 'application/json',
        authorization: 'some JWT'
       }})
```

back end:

```
        try{
            
            const upload_result = await cloudinary.uploader.upload(req.body.fil, {
                public_id: `${user._id}_profile`,
                width:500,
                height:500,
                crop: 'fill'
            })
            res.status(201).json({success:true,message: "good"})
            
        }catch (error){
            res.status(500).json({success:false,message: "Error"})
        }
```

Comment: Try converting the image.path for android into a Blob or Base64 Data URI and passing that as the "file" parameter in your upload request.

Answer (score 0):

per @Michalk: Enable the `includeBase64: true` option for the picker

Instead of `Image.path` use: `data:${image.mime};base64,${image.data}`

```
const res = await client.post('/upload-avatar', JSON.stringify({ data: fil }), {
    headers: {
        'Content-type' : 'application/json',
        authorization: 'JWT JWT
    }
});
```